# How to check if div with particular class exists on a page xpath/php

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to parse a page and check if a certain container exists.

```
$info = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"user-info")]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I'm trying this, but it returns nothing regardless of whether element exists or not (since the container suppose to be empty). How can I get simple true/false?

Comment: What do you mean by *returns nothing*? Is `info` null, is nothing being printed to your console? It'd be easier to answer your question if you've got a log from your console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check only existance of an element with particular class use `DOMXPath::evaluate` function and xpath `boolean()` function:

```
$info = $xpath->evaluate('boolean(//div[contains(@class,"user-info")])');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can check if [`length`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length) property of the returned `DOMNodeList` object is greater than `0` which indicates that the target `div` element is exists :

```
$div = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"user-info")]');
if($div->length > 0) echo "Element exists";
else echo "Element not found";
```